# How to tell sqlmap to resume an exploit from results-*.csv file?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

How to notify SQLMap to resume an exploit from `results-*.csv` file?

Example: `~/.sqlmap/output/results-xxxxxxxxxx.csv`

```
Target URL,Place,Parameter,Techniques
http://example.com:80/login.php,POST,Password,TU
```

Comment: I think you want to use the sessionfile instead: `-s SESSIONFILE      Load session from a stored (.sqlite) file`